# How to get SLIME up and running based on documentation?

Tags: emacs, slime

I'm trying to get started with SBCL (for macOS). I've installed SBCL, but now I'm trying to get Emacs (for macOS) and SLIME working. However, I must be missing something in the docs because when I try this:

```
M-x package-install RET slime RET
```

I get "[No match]".

I'm following the instructions for [SLIME](https://www.common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Installation.html#Installation) and [MELPA](http://melpa.org/#/getting-started). I installed Emacs for macOS 24.5-1 because I'm not sure Emacs 25 has package.el built in.

So what else am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to make Emacs download the package list first by running `M-x list-packages`.  After that, `M-x package-install` should work.

(Also, Emacs 25 does have package.el built in.)

Comment: So nice of the docs to tell you this. How are newbies supposed to figure this out???

Comment: Okay, according to the docs, I'm ready to start slime with 'Esc-x slime'. Apparently not, though, because I'm getting "Searching for program: no such file or directory, lisp". Getting SLIME to work is like pulling teeth! What ELSE am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Did you add `(setq inferior-lisp-program "/opt/sbcl/bin/sbcl")` or similar to your config?

Comment: Yes, I did. But someone told me what ELSE I'm missing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42171736/why-isnt-slime-working.

It's astonishing how arcane all of this is. Programming should not be such an ordeal.