# Why isn't SLIME working?

Tags: emacs, slime

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165169/how-to-get-slime-up-and-running-based-on-documentation) previously, but SLIME still doesn't work. When I try "Esc-x slime", I get "Searching for program: no such file or directory, lisp". Why is it so difficult to get SLIME up and running? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add sbcl or whatever to `slime-lisp-implementations`

Comment: Thanks. This worked. It's astonishing how arcane all of this is.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case (I know this counted for me): you could try [Portacle](https://shinmera.github.io/portacle/), a portable and multiplatform development environment. It gives Emacs25 with Slime, SBCL, Quicklisp and Git packaged together.